# Cropping an image natively in phonegap with allowEdit flag

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am using the following

```
phonegap 3.6.0-0.21.18
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

I need to crop an image natively in phonegap to a fixed dimension of width:650px and height:250px. The call which I use to achieve it as shown below. For some reason phonegap does not see the need to start the cropping tool with the camera when the destination type is DATA_URL.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
quality: 45, 
allowEdit: true, <-- Forces the crop tool to appear if target sizes are different
targetWidth: 650,
targetHeight: 250,
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL, <--- Changed this to work
sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
correctOrientation: true
});
```

But when I change the destinationType:  destinationType.FILE_URI with camera, the crop tool opens up for cropping after photo capture.

The cropping tool appears when I try it with gallery along with the same parameters

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { 
quality: 45, 
allowEdit: true, <-- Forces the crop tool to appear if target sizes are different
targetWidth: 650,
targetHeight: 250,
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,  <-- Didnt have to change for the crop tool to open
sourceType: pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM, 
mediaType : Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
correctOrientation: true
});
```

I dont understand this difference between the camera and the gallery call. Both the code uses the destination type as destinationType.DATA_URL. For camera the crop tool does not open while for gallery it does. Is this some bug in android or phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I think is a performance issue in javascript. I didn't try to crop a image natively but I have a memory problem in iOS. I catch the base64 string (DATA_URL) and I edit it with a javascript plugin. I suppose you need the base64 image too. Otherwise, FILE_URI is better.

Look at the [John Wargo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808751/recieve-a-memory-warning-ios-after-using-camera-with-cordova), maybe that help you

And this cordova documentation:

> NOTE: Photo resolution on newer devices is quite good. Photos selected
>   from the device's gallery are not downscaled to a lower quality, even
>   if a quality parameter is specified. To avoid common memory problems,
>   set Camera.destinationType to FILE_URI rather than DATA_URL.