# Recieve a Memory warning iOS after using camera with Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, camera

When I take a photo, I begin to receive memory warnings continuously. I'm using Cordova 3.5 and the camera plugin with these settings.

```
var _config;      
var pictureSource;
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value.
var encodingType; // enconding type 0=JPG 1=PNG

/**
 * Initialize camera plugin.
 * @param {object} config - settings.
 */
function initialize(config) {
    alert("CAMERA is comming!!");
    // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}

/** 
 * Cordova is ready to be used!
 * @param {object} config - settings.
 */
function onDeviceReady() {

    console.log("CAMERA is READY!!");
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    encodingType = navigator.camera.EncodingType;
    capturePhoto();
}

/**
 * Set camera plugin settings.
 * @param {object} config - settings.
 */
function setConfig(config) {
    _config = config;
}

/**
 * Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string.
 */
function capturePhoto() {
    setConfig({ quality: 20, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL, encodingType: 0});
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, _config);
}

/**
 * Photo is successfully retrieved.
 * @callback getPicture~onPhotoDataSuccess
 * @param {string} imageData - A base64-encoded image.
 */
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    //Edit photo
}
```

I make sure that the quality is low, but it gets slower until it crashes.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What device are you testing this on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by fixing the photo size:

```
 /**
 * Take a picture and get the image as base64-encoded string.
 */
function capturePhoto() {
    setConfig({ quality: 20, targetWidth: 600, targetHeight: 600, correctOrientation: true, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL, encodingType: 0});
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, _config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DATA_URL returns the image as a data stream. Modern, High Resolution cameras simply overload the JavaScript engine because of the size of the string value being returned to the program.  From my Apache Cordova API Cookbook:

"There are issues with using Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL. The camera image contains a lot of data, and converting the image to a string and passing it to a Cordova application to work with exceeds the limits of most any device’s JavaScript engine. Unless you crank down the quality or size of the image, you will most likely find that the application is very slow or crashes when you use this option."

Recommendation is to use FILE_URI instead, you'll never be able to use DATA_URL unless you take very small photos.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know, that's why I set quality to 20. I have to use DATA_URL because there is a photo edition step after taking the photo and I can't load a local file.